# Biml Generated Xml Source (SSIS) has Node_ID column even though the Xml has only 1 node

Tags: xml, datasource, auto-generate, biml, ssis-2017

Using Biml we generate SSIS packages that contain an Xml Source to get data from an Xml file. However this generated XML source includes a column called "Data_Id" even though neither the XSD nor the XML has this column. It generates an error while running the package.

I do not have much experience with Biml nor with C#.

We use a variable to get the name of the Xml file (which includes the date and time the Xml was created) and  fixed XSD schema files which specify the columns to retrieve from the Xml file for each package.

The Xml file contains only 1 node named "Data", which contains all elements.

I've tried setting the ErrorRowDisposition of the Data_Id column to IgnoreFailure and RedirectRow on both the outputpath and the inputpath but this does not help.
I've also tried including the data_id column in the Columns list with property IsUsed="false" but that does not do anything.

We use the following Biml code to generate the Xml source in the package:

```
<XmlSource Name="XML Source" ValidateExternalMetadata = "false">
 <FileNameFromVariableInput VariableName="User.XMLfullPath"/>
 <XmlSchemaFileInput ConnectionName="XSD_for_<#=curTableRow["SourceTableName"]#>"/>
 <Columns>
   <Column SourceColumn="Column2_NAME" IsUsed="false"></Column>
 </Columns>
</XmlSource>
```

However when the package is generated it turns out that the Xml Source contains a "Data_Id" column that is not specified in the XSD schema file nor the XML file.

This column can only be seen when you select Advanced Editor on the Xml source and disappears when you click OK after opening the Xml Source. 
When you normally open the Xml Source by double-clicking it you cannot see the Data_Id column.

This Data_Id column causes an error message when the package runs: "The Data_Id has no mapping to the XML schema".

We would however want to generate the packages and not have to open every single package and within each package the Xml source for it to work.

Some googling revealed that similar "_Id" columns are created by an Xml source in SSIS automatically when the Xml contains multiple Nodes, such that these nodes can later be joined together. However, since our Xml files contain only 1 Node (Data), this Data_Id column should not be generated, but is nonetheless present in the Biml generated SSIS package.

Has anyone had this problem before and/or knows how to get rid of it?